# array to map ordinal y-axis d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis, ordinal

I am trying to develop a scatterplot using d3 but the domain for y-axis is confusing me. y-axis are gonna display patient names and x-axis display their appointment dates. x-axis are working fine, but y-axis are displaying only two patient names.

```
function graph()  {

    var num_patient = Object.keys(patientList).length;
    var patient_names = Object.keys(patientList);
    console.log(patient_names);

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.ordinal().range([height, 0]);

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return parseDate(d.dates); }));
    //y.domain(patient_names.map(function(d)  { return d.name;}));
    y.domain(patient_names);    

    console.log(y.domain());

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .ticks(d3.time.year, 1)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("#punchcard")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

     svg.selectAll("dot")
            .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 3.5)
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); });

     svg.append("g")            // Add the X Axis
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);
}
```

console.log(patient_names) display the names correctly:

```
`["Andrew","Fred","Steve","John"]`
```

console.log(y.domain()) displays an extra undefined object:

```
["Andrew", "Fred","Steve" , "John", undefined]
```

But the y-axis only display Andrew at 0 and Fred at height h. How can I get to display all four names? I cannot hard code them as they are user input values. BTW: I am a beginner with d3 and js.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With ordinal scales, you need to define the range points for the inputs explicitly (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales)). That is, you need to tell the scale explicitly which input value to map to which output. For example:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(["Andrew","Fred","Steve","John"])
          .range([height, height * 2/3, height * 1/3, 0]);
```

You probably want to use the `.rangePoints()` method instead, which allows you to specify an interval that D3 automatically divides based on the number of values in the domain:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(["Andrew","Fred","Steve","John"])
          .rangePoints([height, 0]);
```

Note that for `.rangePoints()` to work properly, you need to set the domain *before* the output range.

Comment: I got this on trying your solution:                          TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'd3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(patient_names)
  .rangePoint([height,0])')

Comment: Sorry, typo -- should be `.rangePoints`. Will fix that.